# can i add formula in maatwebsite excel in laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I need to add formula to cells in maatwesite excel sheets using laravel please help me with this is it possible to add if possible please suggest the code

Comment: Hello, what did you try so far? please share your code

Comment: @satish can you try `WithMapping` method for add formulas into the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Add formulas One of the ways to do it is to use `WithMapping`:

For example, you need to add value in cell-like this **A2+1**

```
use App\Customer;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class CustomersExportFormulas implements FromCollection, WithMapping
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Customer::all();
    }


    public function map($customer): array
    {
        return [
             $customer->id,
            '=A2+1',
            $customer->first_name,
            $customer->last_name,
            $customer->email,
        ];
    }
}
```